# Set a title in Toolbar from fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have been using the latest Toolbar from AppCompatv7 lib.I have placed a textview in the ToolBar ViewGroup And I want to set a title into this Textview from the fragment in my activity.In case of a custom action bar ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity).setcustomView(..) would have done the job.But due to use of this ToolBar I am not able to use that.Also I have implemented a method in my BaseActivity that is inherited by all Activities.This BaseActivity contains my method to initialize a sliding drawer to the left.I have to initialize the initDrawerLayout() method in activity else the drawer would not be initialized.And if I initialize it in fragment its giving me all empty results,neither the toggle button for drawer and nor is the custom title getting set.

This is my initDrawer code..

```
public void initDrawerLayout(String toolbar_text) {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerRelative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_relative);
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_a).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_b).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_c).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_d).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_e).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_f).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_g).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_h).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_i).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_j).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_k).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn_l).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.my_layout).setOnClickListener(this);





            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
            toolbar.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_actionbar_background));
            TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
            mTitle.setText(toolbar_text);
            mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            if (toolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

             mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this,  mDrawerLayout, toolbar,
                    R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close
                );
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                    } else {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                    }
                }
            });
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                    GravityCompat.START);

            mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(
                    android.R.color.transparent));
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        }
    }
```

And this my code in the fragment..

`((FirstActivity) getActivity()).initDrawerLayout(mFirst.name);`
    where mFirst is a object of class Person

and the toolbar code..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Toolbar Title"
                android:textColor="@color/action_text-color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" /> 

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Please help guys..

Comment: The one who down voted this..can you please answer the question before downvoting..I have asked this question after quite a lot of searching.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity (to set your Toolbar Title), you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity as described here: [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Answer (score 63):

I do this like this:
from the fragment call

```
getActivity().setTitle("your title");
```

But where you call it is important, because if each Fragment has it's own title, then one may override the other accidentally, which may be prevented like:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setTitle(getString(R.string.my_title));
    }
}
```

> For example, two Fragments of the same Pager can not be in resume-state at the same time.

Also you can "cast", to call any function of your parent Activity like this:

```
YourActivity mYourActiviy = (YourActivity) getActivity();
mYourActivity.yourActivityFunction(yourParameters);
```

Answer (score 28):

In Kotlin.

In fragment:

```
(activity as YourActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.your_title)
```

In activity:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 15):

If you have setSupportActionBar in Your Activity then you can easily change the toolbar title from your fragment

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer is writen below in the `oncreateview` method of fragments.

```
getActivity().setTitle("your name");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create Interface inside the Fragment. check below:-

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    OnMyFragmentListener mListener;

    // Where is this method called??
    public void setOnMyFragmentListener(OnMyFragmentListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnMyFragmentListener) {
            mListener = (OnMyFragmentListener) context;
            mListener.onChangeToolbarTitle("My Fragment"); // Call this in `onResume()`
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mListener.onChangeToolbarTitle("My Fragment");
    }


    // This interface can be implemented by the Activity, parent Fragment,
    // or a separate test implementation.
    public interface OnMyFragmentListener {
        public void onChangeToolbarTitle(String title);
    }

}
```

In Activity:-

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.OnMyFragmentListener {

    @Override
    public void onChangeToolbarTitle(String title){
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
    }

}
```

This works for me. :)

Comment: Works very well except i'd recommend you just use `onAttach(Context context)` to initialize the `listener` and use `onResume()` to call the listener's methods

Comment: it shouldnt be hardly or complex like that

Answer (score 5):

This has worked for me, in Kotlin. Put this in your fragment class:

```
if (activity != null) {
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.action_history)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If somebody struggles with this problem, this may be useful.

Basically you have 4 options, how to handle that:

- use an interface in order to communicate with your activity, or any other convenient method, like an event bus.
- you call `getActivity().setTitle("Title")`, but in this case you need to attach your `Toolbar` to the `ActionBar` by calling the `setSupportActionBar()` in your activity.
- You can have a public instance of your `Toolbar` and access that instance from the fragment.
- Finally, if you need the instance of your `Toolbar`(you may want to do something else with), you can simply get it this way:

  `Toolbar bar=Toolbar.class.cast(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar));`

Well, the last option would solve the problem only if the `Toolbar` hasn't been passed to the `setSupportActionBar` method.

If it has been, then you need to call this method in your activity:

`supportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`,

which will solve the problem.

However, I would suggest to use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) which will make it a little bit cleaner, here an example:

```
  Toolbar actionBar=findById(getActivity(),R.id.actionBar);
  actionBar.setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: You know what you are doing. Great answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, I use

```
fun onAttach(...){
..
activity?.title = "My Title"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.id_toolbar);

toolbar.setTitle("New Title");
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that for some reason the label was overwritten. I had to change it back to the string resource, in

```
 navigation.xml
```

inside the fragment tag;

```
android:label="@string/android_trivia"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity declare the toolbar as public.

```
public class YourActivity : Activity
{
    public Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = .... // initilize your toolbar
    }
}
```

Then, from your fragment

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).toolbar.Title = "Your Title";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                FragmentManager.BackStackEntry lastBackStackEntry=null;

                int lastBackStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
                if(lastBackStackEntryCount >= 0 )
                {
                    lastBackStackEntry = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(lastBackStackEntryCount);
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+lastBackStackEntryCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(lastBackStackEntryCount == -1)
                {
                    toolbar.setTitle("");
                    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.header_logo);
                }
                else
                {
                    toolbar.setTitle(lastBackStackEntry.getName());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: this will also handle the first fragment problem

Comment: this will help load the title from the backstack tag itself so just need provide the correct tag name also your title of the fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can change the title of your toolbar on the event OnAttach, something like this

```
        var toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        toolbar.Title = "New Title";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom toolbar, this will help you:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Feedback");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the title in activity commiting the fragment and return the fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment, mainFragment).commit();
            toolbar.setTitle("ShivShambhu");
            return contentFragment;
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple solution.
In your activity that extends AppCompatActivity, you can do this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The inside its fragment, you can do this:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    android:background="@color/tool_bar_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Find TextView Id from toolbar**

if you are using Activity

```
 TextView mTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
 mTitle.setText("set your title");
```

if you are using Fragment

```
 TextView mTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
 mTitle.setText("set your title");
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers to multiple questions. Your answers should be tailored to each specific question, and questions that are the same should be flagged as duplicates.