# Why "getActivity().setTitle()" to set the Toolbar title is not working?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have my `MainActivity` and a few fragments, and I want to change the `Toolbar` title depending on the `Fragment` displayed.

I have tried using `getActivity().setTitle(R.string.buscar_futbolista);` in `onCreateView` of the `Fragment`, but is not changing the title. Why?

In my `MainActivity`, in `onCreate` method I have the following:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.inicio);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26998718/21021740

I replaced `getActivity().setTitle(R.string.buscar_futbolista);` by `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.buscar_futbolista);`.

Comment: Because you are in a Fragment, getActivity() will alway return FragmentActivity, for setTitle to work you need AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

In code you have mentioned, you're trying to do two things at once that is setting `actionbar` title and `toolbar` title. That is why its not working.

**Solution:**

If you want to set **title** to your **Actionbar** this is how you can do it:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setTitle("ACTIONBAR TITLE");
```

Now if you want to set **title** to **Custom toolbar** that you have created you can do it like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("TOOLBAR TITLE");
```

**Remember:**

**ActionBar** is the element present at the top of the activity screen. It is a salient feature of a mobile application that has a consistent presence over all its activities.

**Toolbar** is a View included in a layout like any other View. As a regular View , the toolbar is easier to position, animate and control. Multiple distinct Toolbar elements can be defined within a single activity.

Let me know if it you any doubts. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Hi @Shivrajsinh Sarvaiya, thank you for your explanaiton, but I am using a `NoActionBar` theme (in `themes.xml` I have `<style name="Theme.HistoriaDelXCD" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`). This is why I created the `Toolbar` in my `MainActivity`. `toolbar.setTitle()` is working from `MainActivity`, but `getActivity().setTitle(R.string.buscar_futbolista)` from `Fragment` is not changing the `Toolbar` title. I was trying to follow this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34359806/21021740